# Autosuggest values based on another autosuggested input

Tags: php, jquery, autosuggest

I am working on a library type database. Supposed I want to create 2 input fields (using PHP) each having its own autosuggest capability in order to help filter user's selection. However, the values to be populated in field #2 will be dependent upon the value searched and selected by the user in field #1. I wonder if I should even make the 2nd field inactive until a valid value (that exists in the database) is properly searched and selected in field #1.

Field 1: Autosuggesting searches for a list of libraries.

Field 2: Upon entering a proper library in field 1, field 2 would be able to autosuggest books that are contained within that library.

I want to accomplished this 2-step autosuggest all in one page, as opposed to moving the user to a whole another page in order to search the books within the selected library.

I am working with a lot of libraries, so a drop down list doesn't make much sense for field #1.

I have a "books_library" table in my database that each has a bookID as well as a library ID showing that it belongs to that particular library. I can easily populate field #2 autosuggest with all the books, the problem is, how do I filter the autosuggest in field #2 based on the library ID generated from field #1?

Does anyone know a proper name for this sort of project? I could not find anything like this in google. The closest thing is a drop-down list one after another based on values selected in a previous drown down list. But I am working with a lot more data than drop-downs can provide in a user friendly manner.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I wonder if I should even make the 2nd field inactive until a valid
>   value (that exists in the database) is properly searched and selected
>   in field #1.

I would go one step further and not show it until they've done so. It sounds like you want to use the [autocomplete jquery ui plugin](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) (or an autocomplete plugin from some other library - there's more than one.)

As far as using what's been selected from the first text box for the second, bind a function to the select event of the first autocomplete that sends data to the server to prime the "source" before showing the second autocomplete.